# cant turn on mysqld. I moved mysql to an XFS directory and pointed it there

Tags: centos, mysql, database, xfs

hey guys hopefully someone has the answers for this but
these are my errors

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

and in my /etc/log/mysqld.log

```
150403  0:30:26 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
150403 00:30:26  mysqld ended
150403 00:58:32  mysqld started
150403  0:58:32 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/cts4348-node-8.lower-test
150403  0:58:32 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/cts4348-node-8.lower-test
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
150403  0:58:32 [ERROR] Aborting
```

and this is my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/
socket=/mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
```

the funny part is, it was working before, then stop all of the sudden trying to install mantis

I tried these commands to fix them, but still same problem

```
  926  semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t /mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/
  927  semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t /mnt/xfsdisk/
       restorecon -Rv /mnt/xfsdisk/mysql/
        semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/mnt/xfsdisk/mysql(/.*)?"
```

nothing seems to work? any ideas where to point me? (also I do not have a [client] in the my.cnf file.

i am also running centos 5

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "restorecon -RF " and restart MySQL service.

If this does not work, try to set SELINUX into permissive mode by using "setenforce 0". If that work, your SELINUX policy need some other changes.